# Why do many prominent web apps use blue primary button with white text, when it fails the WCAG 2.1 contrast threshold

Tags: accessibility, color, contrast, wcag

WCAG 2.1 says to have a minimum contrast ratio of 4.5:1, but blue primary buttons of Twitter, Figma and Outlook have white text which fails to cross the threshold ratio. Is there another scientific angle to this? [image]

[Update] Even Google images has that color now (with a ratio of 2.55).
[image]

Comment: Has it something to do with an open issue in WCAG repo - https://github.com/w3c/wcag/issues/695

Answer (score 4):

Accessibility modes are likely the reason. Twitter has a [high-contrast mode](https://appuals.com/twitter-increase-contrast-feature/) for users who need it:

> The accessibility setting of the web app now has a new “increase color
> contrast” toggle button. The button once turned on, activates the high
> contrast colors for UI elements. The high contrast mode makes it
> easier for people with visual impairments to use the Twitter Web app.

Outlook's desktop app adopts the operating system's higher-contrast settings when activated.

[image: Mac OS setting to increase contrast]

Outlook - regular contrast mode

[image: Outlook - regular contrast]

Outlook - increase contrast mode

[image: Outlook - high contrast mode]

Unsure why Figma has a lower-contrast button - it doesn't seem to be modal.